# How to I add more values to the following code?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5

I have a line of code in Joomla- "horizontal" and "vertical" are two layout options.

```
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_fwrealestate_search', 
            ($params->get('layout') == 'horizontal')?'horizontal':'vertical'));
```

How would I modify this code to include more layout options?  I tried this but it does not work- I know the : between the values is probably wrong, and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_fwrealestate_search', 
         ($params->get('layout') == horizontal')?'horizontal':'vertical':'islands':'commercial':'vacation':'land'));
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See answer below. What you have is a ternary statement:  If "this" ? "this" : "that". If you need more options, you must put an entire new ternary into "that"

Comment: Do you really need a ternary operator? can't you just use `$params->get('layout')`

Comment: I second the above comment. In this case, you don't seem to need the conditional since the param already contains the string you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_fwrealestate_search', ($params->get('layout') == 'horizontal'?'horizontal':$params->get('layout') == 'vertical'?'vertical':$params->get('layout') == 'islands'?'islands':$params->get('layout') == 'vacation'?'vacation':'land'));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a fast response.  I inserted the code provided and now I'm getting a blank screen???

Comment: Check the second comment to your question. It doesn't look like you need anything more than:         require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_fwrealestate_search', $params->get('layout')));

Comment: Btw, I don't know about Joomla, just what that particular statement for the params is doing in Javascript. It's likely that there is no corresponding layout to the one stored in $params->get('layout') is evaluating to in your statement.